# How do I refer to a display with xinerama enabled?

Tags: xinerama

I'd like to launch gnome-terminal on my second monitor, you'd expect something like:

```
~$ gnome-terminal --display=0:0.1
```

to work but doesn't as RANDR is disabled or not used when xinerama is enabled.

The error I get when trying to launch with this command is:

```
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: 0:0.1
```

I've also tried:

```
~$ export DISPLAY=":0.0"
~$ gnome-terminal --display=$DISPLAY
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".
** (gnome-terminal:1818): WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: Could not open network socket
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no syntax to refer to individual monitors in a screen in a display string.

However, you might be able to use the `--geometry` option to do what you're after.  If you have two monitors side by side and the first is 1920 pixels wide, then the following should position a terminal window at (50,50) on the second screen:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24+1970+50
```

The syntax of the argument is `ROWSxCOLS+X+Y`

Comment: bravo, I ended up with gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24+1440+0 --full-screen